# How to check a PayPal subscription has not been cancelled?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I have a chat site and I am going to make it possible for the users to reserve a nickname for a subscription fee per month. I have been reading up on PayPal documentation and understand how to do such using PHP with the various callbacks from PayPal to check that the initial payment has been confirmed but what I don't understand how to do is how to each month check that the subscription has still been paid/not cancelled, otherwise do something (in this case remove their subscriber account)?

Comment: Are you using 'Payflow' or 'Website Payments Pro' to bill for the subscription? It seems to me they are the two main ways PayPal manages recurring payments. Or are you trying to implement your own system? There's also a extensive list of variables available for subscription based payments in the [PayPal help](https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside).

Answer (score 0):

You can use PayPal IPN feature https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/?mark=IPN.
Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/, there is a "profile_status" variable , PayPal can notify you if profile status is changed.